Mysql Crashing on: [FATAL] Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds
Once a day or two we get the bellow error and the mysql crashingt:
2024-07-14T05:31:59.327696Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012872] [InnoDB] [FATAL] Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.
2024-07-14T05:31:59.327741Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: srv0srv.cc:1878:ib::fatal triggered thread 140039700203264
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2024-07-14T05:31:59Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=1758de1e111952b1f61480360c447dc27d6caddc
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x2130f51]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x397) [0xfee797]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_server_abort()+0x75) [0xfee8e5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_abort()+0xe) [0x212adee]
usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x309) [0x237b9b9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ib::fatal::~fatal()+0xcf) [0x237e2ff]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_error_monitor_thread()+0x7aa) [0x231c41a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(void Detached_thread::operator()<void (*)()>(void (*&&)())+0xca) [0x224a87a]
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0xc2b13) [0x7f5de9854b13]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x81da) [0x7f5dea8bc1da]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f5de8e6be73]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

And before are alot of those:
Mutex at 0x7fde903975e8, Mutex TRX_SYS created trx0sys.cc:565, locked by 140504716736256
--Thread 140504724723456 has waited at trx0sys.h line 598 for 240 seconds the semaphore:
2024-07-13T04:43:26.039036Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012985] [InnoDB] A long semaphore wait:
{}

I also see a lot of those warnings in the logs (I think mostly after the restart):
[Warning] [MY-013865] [InnoDB] Redo log writer is waiting for a new redo log file. Consider increasing innodb_redo_log_capacity.

I couldn't figure out what is the cause of this problem. I increased the innodb_redo_log_capacity by a lot but it happened anyway. I also tried turning off innodb_adaptive_hash_index but it didn't help. I thought of increasing innodb_log_buffer_size which is currently set to 1M because I thouth maybe its causing a transaction to be to slow.
Its important to say that MySQL seems like it stops doing anything in those 600 seconds. I can't connect to the server at this time, CPU is down to nothing and then we get this error and a crush.

Since it is not possible to connect to DB during the downtime, I thought running a Scheduled Event from MySQL itself writing running queries to the disk should do the trick - but I was wrong. Even using a Scheduled Event stopped writing the same time downtime started.
Another thing that I tried is to enable innodb_status_output which logs SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; to stderr every 15 seconds, even this stopped writing to stderr the same time downtime started.
We use MySQL version 8.0.34

show the complete error log, so we can have a better understanding ofn the problem, also check the file system for errors

You are right. I edited my question

that is a crash, you should try to upgrade the version to the latest and eventual think about 8.4.1 as version.

Can you please explain why?

as segmantetion fault, is a problem cause by accessing a memory part, which the program should not have access to, so it genegrates an error and crashes the program, as i don't know which Version you actually have, you should try to upgrade the server to chekc if the programm iws the cause. if the error occurs further you maybe have faulty server hardware

Why do you think it's a segmentation fault? Mysql version 8.0.34

thennupdatenmitn to8,0,38 there where alreday a lot of fixwes

Can you please explain why you think there is a segmentation fault and why should I update mysql? I need to justify updating the DB

The solution was to replace the node that MySQL was running on, this was probably a hardware problem.
After that, the problem never happened again.
